# Find words that contain substring in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I was trying to use wildcard search in Word 2016 to find words that contain certain substring, but I can't figure it out.

E.g. I want all words that contain "a" and I was expecting that `[a-z]{1;}(a)[a-z]{1;}` would find them, but it finds nothing. Why is that?

- `(a)[a-z]{1;}` finds suffixes after "a"
- `[a-z]@(a)` finds prefixes before "a", but naturally won't find words that begin with "a"
- `[a-z]{1;}(a)` finds nothing
- `[a-z]*(a)` or `<[a-z]*(a)` will match even preceding words

So far `[a-z]@(a)[a-z]{1;}` is the best I got, but it won't find words that have any prefix before "a".

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: I've changed my answer. Please test that.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Word 2016's version of wildcard search but from [this article](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_wildcards.html) I think I've found the proper pattern.

```
<(([A-Z]){0,1})@A(([A-Z]){0,1})@>
```

make sure not to turn on "match case".

### Explanation

```
<                                 Start of word
  ([A-Z]){0,1)                    Either no letter or 1 letter
 (            )@                  1 or more of the previous line
                A                 Letter A
                  ([A-Z]){0,1)    Either no letter or 1 letter
                 (            )@  1 or more of the previous line
                                > End of word
```

I think this may work, but this also may be an impossible task.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, that doesn't work ;) For some obscure reason, `[a-z]{1,0}`  won't find anything when followed by a letter and `[a-z]{0,}` actually is invalid.
Btw. I've used `;` as a list separator due to my regional settings.

Comment: I've changed it. Does this work now?

Comment: @timotree why don't you test it the first time and then you wouldn't go wrong. and why don't you test it now that you have changed it

Comment: @barlop I don't have word :-)

Comment: Thanks for the effort @timotree ;) Unfortunately, it's not working either. It indeed might be impossible.

Comment: @psmn If `{0,1}` doesn't work I think you're out of luck.